# Android. Доступ к NavigationDrawer из фрагмента

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Использую NavigationDraver, есть проблема когда запускаешь фрагмент из его меню то соответствующий пункт меню выделяется, но иногда нужно перейти в раздел не через меню а по какому то событию и тогда при открытии меню там подсвечивается предыдущий пункт. Так как он прописан в Activity я не могу напрямую влиять на ег освойства. Подскажите пожалуйста как получить доступ из фрагмента к управлению NavigationDrawer. Можно конечно сделать его static но это ппц костыль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно по разному:

1. У фрагмента есть метод `getActivity()`, результат которого можно скастовать к классу вашей активити и вызвать к-л её метод.
2. Можно воспользоваться библиотеками для оправки/принятия пользовательских событий. В активити подписаться на их получение и в методе-получателе что-то делать с дровером. Посылать, соответственно из фрагмента. Библиотеки [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) и [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)