# Как получить доступ с внешнего класса к переменным внутреннего статического класса

Tags: java, android, классы

Есть такой класс:

```
public class OuterClass {
    int x;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        x = 1;  
    }

    static class StaticClass1 {
        int y1, y2;
        y1 = x;
        ... // методы внутри класса, устанавливают значение y2
        x = y2;
    }

    static class StaticClass2 {
        int z;
        z = x;
    }
}
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы реализовать вышеприведенное намерение через переменные?

Comment: Что вы все-таки хотите сделать? "Дотянуться" из `StaticClass1` и `StaticClass2` до `x` или из `OuterClass` до переменных внутренних классов? Мне кажется заголовок немного не соответствует.

Comment: Дотянуться из StaticClass1 до х, потом из OuterClass до переменных внутренних классов, чтобы передать их значения StaticClass2. Заголовок можно увеличить: "Как получить доступ с внешнего класса к переменным внутреннего статического класса И ОБРАТНО".

Comment: в общем случае надо экземпляр объекта передавать как-то, статические внутренние классы в этом плане отличаются от обычных классов только тем, что им доступны приватные члены внешнего класса. В вашем случае - [getActivity() и приведение типа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473737/).

Answer (score 2):

Статические вложенные классы не имеют доступа к **нестатическим** полям и методам внешнего класса. Только с передачей ссылки на экземпляр внешнего класса, например, так:

```
static class StaticClass2 {
        int z;
        z = x;

        public void doSomething(OuterClass outerClass) {
            outerClass.x = 0;
        }
    }
```

А к полям внутренних классов обратиться просто:

```
OuterClass.StaticClass1 staticClass = new OuterClass.StaticClass1();
staticClass.y1 = 0;
```

Если во вложенном статическом классе часто происходят обращения к полям внешнего класса, возможно, имеет смысл завести там поле, хранящее ссылку на переданный экземпляр внешнего класса, и инициализировать его в конструкторе вложенного класса, чтобы остальным методам не передавать его. Но тогда возникают сомнения в правильности выбранного подхода: зачем вам статический вложенный класс, если ему для выполнения своих функций все время нужна ссылка на экземпляр внешнего класса? Может, просто сделать его нестатическим?